# MySQL ORDER BY from subquery lost by GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table x :

**id       lang        externalid**

1        nl            10

2        nl            11

3        fr             10

From this table I want al the rows for a certain lang and externalid, if the externalid doesn't exist for this lang, I want the row with any other lang.

The subquery sorts the table correct, but when I add the group by, the sort of the subquery is lost. This works in older mysql versions but not in 5.7.

```
(
 SELECT
  *
 FROM
  x
 ORDER BY FIELD(lang, "fr") DESC, id
)
 as y
group by externalid
```

I want the query to return the records with id 2 & 3. So for each distinct external id, if possible the lang = 'fr', else any other lang.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Please fix the SQL query you have posted this SQL query is invalid SQL.. also post the results you expect

Comment: Please tell us what you want to appear, specifically, when you `GROUP BY externalid`.  Your group by clause makes very little sense as it is.

Comment: "all the rows for a certain lang and externalid" - Does that mean that unlike in your example there can be several records for one `lang` and `externalid` (e.g. two records, both with `lang = nl and externalid = 10`)? And you want to select all these records? And if there is no record matching the given `lang` and `externalid`, you want one single result record with the given `externalid` and whichever `lang`?

Comment: There can't be two records with the same lang and externalid. 

The second part is correct. I want a single result with the given externalid and lang. If there isn't record with the lang, the externalid with whichever lang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking of given `externalid` and `land`. No need to group by `externalid` hence; use a mere `where` clause instead.

Combined with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` you get the record you want (i.e. the desired language if such a record exists, else another one).

```
select *
from mytable
where externalid = 10
order by lang = 'fr' desc
limit 1;
```

**UPDATE:** Okay, according to your comment you want to get the "best" record per `externalid`. In standard SQL you'd use `ROW_NUMBER` for this. Other DBMS have further solutions, e.g. Oracle's `KEEP FIRST` or Postgre's `DISTINCT ON`. MySQL doesn't support any of these. One way would be to emulate `ROW_NUMBER` with variables. Another would be to use above query as a subquery per `externalid` to find the best records:

```
select *
from mytable
where id in
(
  select
    (
      select m.id
      from mytable m
      where m.externalid = e.externalid
      order by m.lang = 'fr' desc
      limit 1
    ) as best_id
  from (select distinct externalid from mytable) e
);
```

Comment: I didn't express myself correctly. I want all records for the distinct external ids.

I want the query to return the records with id 2 and 3 from the question.

Comment: Okay, that's a bit complicated in MySQL. I've added a query for this to my answer. This query accesses the table multiple times. An alternative would be the use of variables. You will find this approch in other SO threads.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But the query is slow. If i use variables, will the query be faster?

Comment: Probably, yes. You'd select the records once and used variables to number the records per external ID (giving the 'fr' record #1 if it exists); then you keep all #1 records and be done without looking again at the table.

Comment: Is this the correct way to do this? Or can it be done better?
`
    SELECT *
    FROM
    ( 
    SELECT @prev_externalid := @externalid AS prev_externalid,
    @externalid := externalid as externalid,
    @externalid_index := if(@prev_externalid = @externalid, @externalid_index+1, @externalid_index := 0) AS externalid_index,
    tbl_seo.*
    FROM mytable ORDER BY externalid ASC, lang = 'fr' DESC
    ) as mytable WHERE externalid_index = 0;`

Comment: I must admit I don't know. I don't work with MySQL and always found their variables in queries a bit obscure. Usually the position in a select clause doesn't matter. If that applies for MySQL variable assignments as well, then it is left to chance whether `@prev_externalid := @externalid` or `@externalid := externalid` happens first. As said: I don't know. Maybe this is something you want to ask in a new request. I am sure there are many MySQL guys fully understanding the concept and being ready to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery generates a result set (a virtual table) that's passed to your outer query.

All SQL queries, without exception, generate their results in *unpredictable order* unless you specify the order completely in an `ORDER BY` clause.

*Unpredictable* is like *random,* except worse. Random implies you'll get a different order every time you run the query. *Unpredictable* means you'll get the same order every time, until you don't.

MySQL ordinarily ignores `ORDER BY` clauses in subqueries (there are a few exceptions, mostly related to subquery `LIMIT` clauses). Move your `ORDER BY` to the top level query.

**Edit**.  You are also misusing MySQL's notorious nonstandard extension to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Don't think that it helps to remove the ORDER BY to the outer query.. Because MySQL will run the GROUP BY before the ORDER BY..

Comment: Thanks, for the help. Moving the ORDER BY to the top level query doesn't fix the problem because of the reason you explained.